# A photo doesn't appear on my main text and I can't find the issue

Tags: graphics, titles

I want to insert a logo on my title page but as you can see at the top left, it's just a black rectangle. Please help me find the issue.

```
\documentclass[12pt,demo]{article} 

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\definecolor{titlepagecolor}{cmyk}{1,.60,0,.40}
\definecolor{namecolor}{cmyk}{1,.50,0,.10} 
\newtheorem*{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\NN}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\QQ}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\CC}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\bd}{\textbf}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\newgeometry{left=2.5cm}
\pagecolor{titlepagecolor}
\noindent
\includegraphics{äpplet.png}
\color{white}
\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule{1.3\textwidth}{1pt}}
\par
\noindent
\textbf{\textsc{Muhammad Ahmedov}} \textcolor{gray}{\textsf{NA17}}
\vfill
\noindent
{\huge \textsc{Astronomi - instuderingsuppgifter}}
{\large \textsc{Naturvetenskaps specialisering}}
\vskip\baselineskip
\textsf{APRIL 25, 2020}
\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry 
\nopagecolor
```

[image]

Comment: Side effect of [demo].

Comment: How can I change it? What code should I replace it with?

Comment: Just remove "demo" from line 1.

Comment: I did but then the page gets errored, that black rectangle is not even there anymore its just a black line rectangle with no color in it. And the text is inside the rectangle.

Comment: Maybe rename the file `äpplet.png` to something that does not have an accent, like `applet.png`?